# How to pass schema as parameter to a stored procedure in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters, schema

I have a stored procedure to select a list of data based on two tables. The first table is a fixed one: `CO.Country`. But the second table can be one of a number of tables. The name of the table itself is the same: `Location`. But, the schema of the tables are different: `ABD.Location, CGA.Location, GBN.Location.`

The user will select the schema from the application, then the schema chosen will be passed to the stored procedure as a parameter.

But there's an error when I parse the stored procedure while creating it.

Is there anyway to pass the schema name as a parameter?

Comment: Show your stored procedure. What did you try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [DynamicSql](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20815/Building-Dynamic-SQL-In-a-Stored-Procedure)

Try like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_name
   @schema VARCHAR(25)
AS

DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(1000)
SET @query='SELECT * FROM ' +@schema +'.Location'
EXECUTE(@query)
```

Comment: This did the trick. I tried using standard stored procedure query: select * from @schema.Location. Couldn't even execute. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If it's necessary for me have normal query(without DynamicSql) is it possible to pass the schema as variable in this kind of query ?

Comment: @Misi I think no. you need to construct query as string, hence u must use dynamic sql.

Comment: Just for awareness/cautionary purposes, it's worth pointing out that this approach is vulnerable to SQL injection attack. For example, if the parameter was a bit larger (`VARCHAR(35)`) then calling the SP with `EXEC dbo.proc_name @schema = 'sys.stats;DROP PROC proc_name;--'` would cause the procedure to remove itself.

Comment: It looks like the vulnerability to SQL injection attack could be avoided by doing `SET @query='SELECT * FROM ' +QUOTENAME(@schema) +'.Location'`