# ASP.NET MVC Multi tenant Application using Single DB Multiple Schema : Calling Store Procedures from the application tries to access dbo tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, multi-tenant

I am developing a multi tenant application using ASP.NET MVC, SQL Server, Dapper with single db and multiple schema for each tenant. 
A tenant will be assigned a db user who owns the tenant schema. I have a set of tables in dbo and another set shared by all schema.

Say I have `dbo.Tenant` and `anySchema.Table1`. From my application with connection string set for  anyschema user, if i call `select * from Table1` it returns the values from `anySchema.Table1`. If i have the same query in a store procedure, it throws an error as it tries to access `dbo.Table1`.

I have provided execute access to dbo for the tenant db user as single SP is being shared by all tenant which is at `dbo.SP_Name`

How can i execute the store procedure logged in as the tenant db user, accessing `Table1` of the anyschema so that single SP can be used by all tenants.

Comment: Did you give the execute access for the SP to the anySchema. This was not mentioned in your post. Can you check it.

Comment: Yes I have given execute permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume we have two users in our database `tenant1` and `tenant2` with their own schemas (also called `tenant1` and `tenant2`).

We create a `Contacts` table for each tenant so we have `tenant1.Contacts` and `tenant2.Contacts`.

Within our application we execute the following SQL using Dapper. We are using a tenant specific connection string that uses the tenant's SQL Server login details.

```
select * from Contacts
```

Since we did not specify the schema within the SQL it is *inferred* from the default schema of the user under which the SQL executed. So for `tenant1` it will query `tenant1.Contacts` and for `tenant2` it will query `tenant2.Contacts`.

Now we'll create a stored procedure in the `dbo` schema that executes the same query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetContacts
AS
BEGIN
    select * from Contacts
END
GO
```

Note that I've *not* specified a schema in the Stored Procedure's SQL.

When we execute the stored procedure from our application the schema of the *stored procedure* can still be inferred from the current user **but the SQL within the SP infers the schema from that of the SP**. So if the SP belongs to the `dbo` schema it will execute the query against the `dbo.Contacts` table.

This is what is happening in your situation. You have created a stored procedure in the `dbo` schema and expecting it to execute the SQL against the *tenant's* default schema.

You have a few options

1. Pass the schema to your stored procedure as a parameter and use dynamic SQL - [How to pass schema as parameter to a stored procedure in sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436872/how-to-pass-schema-as-parameter-to-a-stored-procedure-in-sql-server)
2. Create a version of the SP for each tenant e.g. `tenant1.SP_Name`, `tenant2.SP_Name`
3. Don't use stored procedures.

Comment: Thanks Ben for the answer. I chose option 1 - dynamic sql in SP.